# 'OAuthModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class error upon upgrade to Ng 16

Tags: angular

I have followed the upgrade path from Ng 14 through 16.
The error that OAuth does not appear to be an Ng Module class makes no sense.  It is an Ng Core module, not a custom or feature one.  It is wrapped in @NgModule({}) decorator.  When I comment the line with OAuthModule out, the code compiles.

Here is the package.json file, which Jocopo Sciampi requested.  Somehow the block quote and the code block do not respect new lines, I don't see how to make this look better but all the file is here:

> {
> "name": "oh1_newgen.webui",
> "version": "0.0.0",
> "scripts": {
> "ng": "ng",
> "start": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --port 4200",
> "start:dev": "echo 'Starting (Dev)...' && ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check",
> "build": "ng build",
> "prod-build": "ng build --configuration production",
> "build-high-mem": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build",
> "test": "ng test",
> "lint": "ng lint",
> "e2e": "ng e2e"
> },
> "private": true,
> "dependencies": {
> "@angular/animations": "16.2.12",
> "@angular/common": "16.2.12",
> "@angular/compiler": "16.2.12",
> "@angular/core": "16.2.12",
> "@angular/forms": "16.2.12",
> "@angular/localize": "16.2.12",
> "@angular/platform-browser": "16.2.12",
> "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "16.2.12",
> "@angular/platform-server": "16.2.12",
> "@angular/router": "16.2.12",
> "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.10.2",
> "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.30",
> "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.14.0",
> "@ngrx/effects": "^15.4.0",
> "@ngrx/entity": "^15.4.0",
> "@ngrx/router-store": "^15.4.0",
> "@ngrx/store": "^15.4.0",
> "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^15.4.0",
> "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-editor": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-menu": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-notification": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-progressbar": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-sortable": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-toolbar": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "14.2.0",
> "@progress/kendo-data-query": "1.7.0",
> "@progress/kendo-drawing": "1.19.0",
> "@progress/kendo-licensing": "1.3.3",
> "@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap": "7.0.2",
> "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^10.0.3",
> "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
> "automapper-ts": "^1.9.0",
> "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
> "core-js": "^2.6.5",
> "jquery": "3.5.0",
> "ngx-bootstrap": "^10.3.0",
> "oidc-client": "^1.9.0",
> "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
> "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
> "tslib": "^2.0.0",
> "zone.js": "~0.13.3"
> },
> "devDependencies": {
> "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.10",
> "@angular/cli": "16.2.10",
> "@angular/compiler-cli": "16.2.12",
> "@angular/language-service": "16.2.12",
> "@ngrx/schematics": "^15.4.0",
> "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
> "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
> "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
> "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
> "jasmine-core": "4.0.0",
> "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
> "karma": "~6.3.2",
> "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
> "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
> "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
> "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
> "typescript": "^5.1.6"
> },
> "optionalDependencies": {
> "protractor": "~7.0.0",
> "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
> "tslint": "~6.1.0"
> }
> }

Here is the error in full:

> Build at: 2023-12-12T19:46:53.836Z - Hash: 1e69f9d48893081c - Time: 3074ms
> Error: src/app/app.module.ts:77:12 - error NG6002: 'OAuthModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.
> 77   imports: imports,
> node_modules/angular-oauth2-oidc/angular-oauth-oidc.module.d.ts:4:22
> 4 export declare class OAuthModule {
> ~~~~~~~~~~~
> This likely means that the library (angular-oauth2-oidc) which declares OAuthModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

I've tried upgrading the "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^10.0.3" line in package.json up through 15.0.1.  I took the max of any major version, that is, the highest option for 11, 12, 13, 14 and 15.  This does not clear the error.
As mentioned, commented out the line for the OAuth module:

> let imports = [
> BrowserModule,
> BrowserAnimationsModule,
> CoreModule,
> SharedModule,
> AppRoutingModule,
> DropDownsModule,
> ***OAuthModule.forRoot(),***

The code will compile with this commented out.

Here is the code for the file for OAuth, of course this is Ng Core. Still checked it for some obvious typo, syntax error that might be there:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';

import { OAuthModuleConfig } from './oauth-module.config';

import { NullValidationHandler } from './token-validation/null-validation-handler';

export declare class OAuthModule {
static forRoot(config?: OAuthModuleConfig, validationHandlerClass?: typeof NullValidationHandler): ModuleWithProviders<OAuthModule>;}
```

Nothing jumps out here as being an obvious error.

There is a note in the upgrade path for the hop to 15, to make sure Ivy is removed.  It was already not there.

Tried to install Ivy to see if this would fix it -- perhaps 16 is expecting Ivy?  Did not work.

This is all Ng code so I don't see what would be causing this issue.

Could use some ideas.

Comment: Can you please add your `package.json` file?

Comment: are you still using an AppModule?

Comment: https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/releases obviously this lib was not tested on ng 16

Comment: And it does not seem that this will be solved soon: https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/issues/1329

Comment: Interesting question "Are we still using an AppModule" -- why would we not be :) ?  We must really be behind the times.
I'll read up on these other links.  Thanks for these.